# Handle sqlplus substitution variables (&&vars) in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

my project is trying to migrate to liquibase but the lack of support for bind variables is making this difficult.

During our deployment we have sql scripts containing sqlplus substitution variables, like for example.

```
-- load_seed.sql ---
insert into <table>
values('&&host', '&&port', '&&user');
```

The value of these variables is different per environment, therefore we define profiles like these.

```
<DEV_profile.sql>
DEFINE host='dev.company.org'
DEFINE port=4008
..

<UAT_profile.sql>
DEFINE host='uat.company.org'
...
```

and the we run the deployment like this:

```
./deploy.ksh DEV

---- deploy.ksh ---
sqlplus <<END
<connection>
@$1_profile
@load_seed
```

The correct profile is picked up at execution time and the variables replaced.

Could you please suggest how to handle a case like this with Liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent functionality in Liquibase is provided by [changelog parameters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html).

In your changelog, you define parameters, which are basically key-value pairs, and liquibase decides which value to use based on the value of a `context` or a `label` or a `dbms`.

When you want to apply the changeset to a given environment, you specify the `context` or `label` on the command line or in the liquibase.properties. Liquibase can determine the `dbms` based on the connection URL.

Here's an example that is somewhat similar to what you describe:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="host" value="dev.company.org" context="DEV"/>
    <property name="port" value="4008" context="DEV"/>
    <property name="user" value="DEV_USER" context="DEV"/>

    <property name="host" value="uat.company.org" context="UAT"/>
    <property name="port" value="4321" context="UAT"/>
    <property name="user" value="UAT_USER" context="UAT"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="joe">
      <insert tableName="someTableName">
        <column name="host" type="varchar(255)" value="${host}"/>
        <column name="port" type="varchar(8)" value="${port}"/>
        <column name="user" type="varchar(255)" value="${user}"/>
      </insert>    
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steve, much appreciated. Does this mean we need to replace in our sql scripts all &&vars in ${vars} ?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html

does not support sql changelog property substitution.   you would have to migrate to (xml, yaml, json)

Comment: @Konqui I don't understand. How is "does not support sql changelog property substitution. you would have to migrate to (xml, yaml, json)" not answering? The link just backs up the claim with "Currently, changelog property substitution is not available in SQL format."